How to convert a 3D point from Global coordinates to Local coordinates?
I have a point A = (Tx=-27.95, Ty=-94.68, Tz=-49.53, Q0=0.3222, Qx=-0.0062, Qy=-0.0092, Qz=0.9466).
Point A is a Global coordinate.
Now, Point A is my reference local coordinate axes
I have a second point B = (Tx=100.77, Ty=-124.18, Tz=31.33, Q0=0.6773, Qx=0.6166, Qy=0.4012, Qz=0.0000. Point B is a Global coordinate.
I would now like to calculate point B in the local reference coordinate. Could you help me?
The point B in the local coordinate should be:
Tx=-120.02, Ty=-55.62, Tz=16.23, Q0=0.2105, Qx=0.5833, Qy=-0.4482, Qz=-0.6439

First you have to find, what a transform describe your quaternion. It can
transform points from local to global frame or from global to local.
Second, transform your point from global to local.

point_in_local = quat_local_from_global * point_in_global or
point_in_local = quat_global_from_local.inverted() * point_in_global


Hello @minorlogic, Thanks for your reply! We want to transform points from global to local. I have added the real points and the expected points in local coordinate (x=-120.02, Ty=-55.62, Tz=16.23, Q0=0.2105, Qx=0.5833, Qy=-0.4482, Qz=-0.6439). Could you do a favor and demonstrate with your formula you get B (x=-120.02, Ty=-55.62, Tz=16.23, Q0=0.2105, Qx=0.5833, Qy=-0.4482, Qz=-0.6439) in local coordinate?

As telepath can i guess you are talking about "rigid transform" as [rotation, translation] ??

the context: A single point circulating in a 3D space and which must be referenced to a local coordinate axis. Point A is my reference local coordinate axes. Point B is the point circulating in  a 3D Space.
